# Visual tree representation After filtering

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm working on a Django app, I want to make some kind of tree of nodes and leafs like [this example](http://www.chesstree.net/). How I can implement that using html-css-javascript ? Is there any library or framework that helps ?

Answer (score 1):

For js graphing id recommend [GO.js](https://gojs.net/latest/index.html) it is free to evaluate, dynamic and fairly user friendly

Comment: Thank you, do not hesitate to propose another free alternative if you know please.